# Authorize.net SIM using php

Tags: php, authorize.net

This is the first time I have tried to use Authorize.net. I thought it would be simple, but there just isn't much in the way of Sample Code.
I want to use the form that is hosted on the authorize.net server.

First of all I am confused about the Finger print. Do I use the Transaction Key or the Signature Key?

I get the same error whether I use the Transaction Key or the Signature Key. I get this error code: (99) This transaction cannot be accepted.

```
            date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
            $xyz_x_fp_timestamp = time() ;
            $xyz_x_fp_sequence = $xyz_x_fp_timestamp - 1489881251 ;//this will generate a unique number every second

            $xyz_x_login = '123123123123';
            $xyz_x_amount = 25.00;
            $my_key = '222222222222222222222222';

            $hash_input = $xyz_x_login.'^'.$xyz_x_fp_timestamp.'^'.$xyz_x_fp_sequence.'^'.$xyz_x_amount.'^';
            $xyz_x_fp_hash = hash_hmac('sha512', $hash_input ,$my_key);
            ?>
    <div class="entry-content">
    <form method="post" action="https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll">

    <input type="hidden" name="x_login" value="<?php echo $xyz_x_login; ?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="x_show_form" value="PAYMENT_FORM" >
    <input type="hidden" name="x_type" value="AUTH_CAPTURE" >
    <input type="hidden" name="x_fp_hash" value="<?php echo $xyz_x_fp_hash; ?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="x_fp_sequence" value="<?php echo $xyz_x_fp_sequence; ?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="x_fp_timestamp" value="<?php echo $xyz_x_fp_timestamp; ?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="x_amount" value="<?php echo $xyz_x_amount; ?>" >
    <p><br/><br/><input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Pay $<?php echo $xyz_x_amount; ?> Now" ><br/></p>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The fingerprint needs to be MD5, not SHA512. It uses your transaction key.

```
$xyz_x_fp_hash = hash_hmac('md5', sprintf('%s^%s^%s^%s^',
    $xyz_x_login,
    $xyz_x_fp_sequence,
    $xyz_x_fp_timestamp,
    $xyz_x_amount
),  $my_key);
```

[Official Documentation](https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A590&actp=LIST)

A couple of notes:

1. You don't need to set the timezone to use `time()`. It always returns the current Unix timestamp which is always in UTC (i.e. timezone independant).
2. Your random number isn't actually random. A slightly better way to generate a random sequence is to use [`rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php). For very sensitive applications it has its own limitations but it works well in this application. (`$xyz_x_fp_sequence = rand(0, 10000);`)

.

```
<?php
    $xyz_x_fp_timestamp = time() ;
    $xyz_x_fp_sequence  = rand(1, 10000);
    $xyz_x_login        = '123123123123';
    $xyz_x_amount       = 25.00;
    $my_key             = '222222222222222222222222';
    $xyz_x_fp_hash = hash_hmac('md5', sprintf('%s^%s^%s^%s^',
        $xyz_x_login,
        $xyz_x_fp_sequence,
        $xyz_x_fp_timestamp,
        $xyz_x_amount
    ),  $my_key);
?>
    <div class="entry-content">
    <form method="post" action="https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll">

    <input type="hidden" name="x_login" value="<?php echo $xyz_x_login; ?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="x_show_form" value="PAYMENT_FORM" >
    <input type="hidden" name="x_type" value="AUTH_CAPTURE" >
    <input type="hidden" name="x_fp_hash" value="<?php echo $xyz_x_fp_hash; ?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="x_fp_sequence" value="<?php echo $xyz_x_fp_sequence; ?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="x_fp_timestamp" value="<?php echo $xyz_x_fp_timestamp; ?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="x_amount" value="<?php echo $xyz_x_amount; ?>" >
    <p><br/><br/><input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Pay $<?php echo $xyz_x_amount; ?> Now" ><br/></p>
    </form>
```

Comment: If that helped you be sure to [accept my answer as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).